# Decimal column, Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, record

I have checked error again and I found out that error is reported because of decimal column in access database. It has something to do with rounding numbers and comparing those numbers to first data that I fetch from table.

Comment: Provide the SQL Code for the generated update command. I'd generally suggest you manually create the update commands.

Comment: @Remou : That link is not the same error as mine!

Comment: That is a completely new question since your edit.

Comment: wait, is this a question and answer in 1 post now?

Comment: Well, the question is included in title, and I edited the body after I discovered the problem.. I also provided solution in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Solution is to use:

```
                    cb = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(DbAdapter);
                    cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;

                    DbAdapter.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();

                    DbAdapter.Update(DbData);
```